# Make a subsite go directly to Access App, and App back to Home site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I am very new to Sharepoint (using 2013), so please bear with me if I use the wrong terms here:

My top-level site is going to break down into several subsites (3 for now) due to needing different permission levels for people depending on the site. What I would like is to have a subsite that is where an Access App lives (the app is already built and tested on a test site, just building the actual Sharepoint site it will live on for good now), and I would like it so that when someone clicks on the subsite, it will go directly to the Access App (no home page or landing page), and when exiting the Access App (clicking the "Back to Site" link at the top) I would like it to return to the top-level site.

I have discovered I can remove the link to the home page of the subsite in my list of links, and add a link that goes directly to the App, but I'm hoping there is some way to make the app and subsite behave differently all together, since I want that "Back to Site" link to go to the top-level.

I need the app on a subsite as we want only 3 or 4 people to be able to actually update the database, and everyone else just views it in-browser, however, everyone needs to be able to check out documents and work with a OneNote notebook as well, so the subsite is necessary.

If making it actually behave this way is impossible, could you suggest a good way to get people back to the top-level site when they go out of the database?

Thanks,
~Sydney

Comment: So I have been continuing to research this issue and while there is no obvious answer, I have a lead - a friend indicated that I may be able to edit the default.aspx that controls that site. Only problem is, I can't find where the Access Web App's default.aspx is being stored in Sharepoint Designer in order to try and find the changes. If this rings any bells with anyone, please let me know, because I can't find the App anywhere in my Sharepoint Designer. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, researching, and fiddling around with every bit of navigation I could find, I have to give up on actually achieving what I was looking for (a way to change the links at the top of an Access Web App). I could not find the default.aspx anywhere to make any adjustments to it.

What I did find was an agreeable workaround for my specific situation. I found that in addition to the default.aspx for the app, there is also a built-in "viewer.aspx" which has no navigation bar at the top of the app. My workaround was to change the link to my Access App from the top-level site, so that it goes to the viewer.aspx instead of default.aspx. This way there is no direct link to the subsite, and no "Back to Site" link for people to click on and get confused. I also turned on the top-level site's Publishing so that I could make my links open in new tabs, so that my users don't have to click back a bunch of times to get back to the top-level site. For my situation, this was the best solution to the problem. I hope that this answer will help others who have a similar struggle where they need unique permissions (and therefore subsites), but also desire unique navigation.

Thanks,
~Sydney